# What word (e.g. eventually vs potentially) does express better the following scenario?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, sentence

The scenario:

> a) **John believes that Peter Parker has a PhD degree.**
>   b) **Peter Parker is the spider man, but John does not know about this.**

Which sentence does express the scenario in the best way?

> 1) John **eventually** believes that the spider man has a PhD degree.
>   2) John **potentially** believes that the spider man has a PhD degree.
>   ?) or something that is offered by you

I am interested in more everyday-used words (a layman's words) not in technical one (like, "extensionally").
Does the position of adverbs matters in this case?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about logic, not English.

Comment: Isn't this related to semantics (which is included in linguistics)?

Comment: John has probably not even considered whether or not Spiderman has a degree.

Comment: It is related to linguistic semantics, namely, to the understanding of words "eventually" and "finally". lexical semantics are sometimes language dependent and in this example I was interested in English as it is not my native language.

Comment: One candidate word would be "extensionally" but I don't think this word is often used in this context by a layman than "unwittingly" or "unknowingly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stipulating to the illogicality of the construction, words that might work in this context are unknowingly and unwittingly. John unknowingly believes that spiderman has a PhD.

Comment: How can one unknowingly believe something? Do I unknowingly believe that black is white? Do you unknowingly believe that William the Conqueror was the grandson of an Englishman? You will need to redefine the word *believe: accept (something) as true; feel sure of the truth of.*

Comment: From the person's perspective who believes (therefore knows) that Peter is the Siderman, and  believe (therefore knows) that (a), then he will most probably say that "John believes that the spider man has a PhD degree.", he will ascribe this believe wrongly to John. And so, I am wondering which sentence will describe best the scenario.

Comment: Here I have in mind this: know = belief + true, when I talk about belief and knowledge.

Comment: this answers is acceptable, since from the actual worlds perspective "John believes that Peter Parker, who actually refers to a spiderman, has a PhD", but at the same time he can be unaware of that he believes that a spider man has a PhD.

Answer (score 1):

Fibo, the presentation of your question as a logical  argument makes the answer easier if you follow the line of reasoning. You can't have two premises in one of your lines, only one.

If "A believes B" is true, and
if "B equals C." is true, then  (**not** B equals C, but also, if "D")
"A believes C." is true.

Adverb placement doesn't matter.

John believes that Peter Parker has a PhD degree.
John does not know that Peter Parker is Spiderman.
Therefore John does not know that Spiderman has a PhD.

Peter Parker is Spiderman.
John knows Peter Parker.
Therefore John knows Spiderman.  True.

John knows Peter Parker, but (not ok)

If the first premise is true, and the second premise is true, then the conclusion must follow the two premises logically.

Yours are not logical conclusions, because your argument is not set up correctly.

Comment: My scenario is very well consistent.
But your arguments are wrong:
In the first example, imagine the scenario where:
 a) J believes PP has PhD, b) J believes SM has PhD, c) he believes that PP and SM are different persons.
So, you first argument is invalid since in the above example premises are tru but conclusion isn't.
The similar kind of example can be given for to you second argument.
-
My question was to find proper English expression for a scenario, namely, if eventually and potentially are understood the way scenario is given.

Comment: @FiboKowalsky - Ouch! Your argument above is **terribly illogical** - that is a completely invalid conclusion. You are incorrect, not I, I"m forced to say. Read up on logical arguments.

Comment: @mediac - You gave me a "valid" argument and I showed that it is not valid by giving the counterexample. Now if I am wrong show me that my example is impossible.
Btw, there are other logics than classical one, and these logics are created to tolerate "inconsistencies".

Comment: @FiboKowalsky - I doubt anything I say will convince you, as you have made up your mind to be correct no matter how absurd your arguments. Fine, no skin off my nose.

Answer (score -1):

3) John **implicitly** believes that the spider man has a PhD degree.